Equilibrium in physics
We know that harmonic oscillator or pendulum will not reach a equilibrium at infinite time. But why a system of gas molecules reaches equilibrium (entropy of an isolated system will tend to increase over time, reaching a maximum at equilibrium)?
What happens if we take system of harmonic oscillators/ pendulums like gas molecules?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Actually, a real harmonic oscillator/pendulum will reach its equilibrium (in infinite time but with exponential dampening). The real problem is the Hamiltonian approximation that excludes the coupling to a temperature bath, despite the knowledge that all systems have a temperature >0 due to the third law of thermodynamics. If we analyze a harmonic oscillator that is weakly coupled to a temperature bath, then there will be automatic dampening. What you are looking at here is the consequence of a short time limit approximation. It is not how a real harmonic system behaves.

In short, it has to do with dissipation. I will start with a very qualitative answer.
A classical pendulum (or oscillator) does not exchange energy/heat with the environment so it is "stuck" in its oscillatory state.
If you add dissipation (friction) then the oscillator eventually stops (equilibrium state). However, I assume you talk about microscopic systems.
If you were to add a heat reservoir (and your oscillator is small enough) you would get that the pendulum gives some of its energy to the reservoir and the reservoir would give some of its energy to the pendulum until an equilibrium state is reached in which the pendulum on average is not oscillating but every now and then it receives a "kick" from the environment and moves a bit.
The issue is that the concept of (thermodynamic) equilibrium applies to big systems with multiple components. It is a bit of a stretch to talk about the equilibrium of a single isolated pendulum.
Instead, if you put a pendulum in a box with (a lot of) air molecules at temperature $T$ the system will indeed equilibrate. A macroscopic pendulum will stop (it gives all of its energy to the environment and it is too big for the energy of the environment to move it substatially), while a microscopic one will vibrate (as now the energy of the enviornment is high enough for it to move) with a given average energy given by the Boltzmann factor $\approx k_B T$.
A more quantitative answer would be that if you put a (1D) oscillator with mass $m$, i.e. a system with energy $$E=p^2/2m+m\omega^2x$$ in a box at temperature $T$ with which it can exchange heat then the system eventually reaches a state in which the oscillator is described by the Boltzmann's ditribution
$$\rho(x, p)\approx e^{-E/k_B T}$$
which is an oscillator that on average is at its rest position but it "vibrates" around it with an average energy of $k_B T$, half of it due to its motion (kinetic energy) and half of it due to its oscillation (potential energy).
In summary, equilibrium is based on the fact that dissipations in the system (due to the pendulum hitting air molecules and the reverse) is connected to fluctuations in the system (i.e. the fact that the system reaches an equilibrium state around which it oscillates). Notice that the above in principle applies also to a big pendulum, just its mass and size are big enough that its kinetic and potential energy are negligible, i.e. since
$${1\over 2}m v^2 \approx {k_B T\over 2}$$ you get a speed of
$$v \approx \sqrt{{k_B T\over m}}$$ and for a 1 Kg pendulum that would correspond to $\approx 10^{-10}$ m/s, that is 10 nm/s, whereas if your pendulum is 1 pico-kilogram what would be roughly 50 $\mu m/s$ which for a microscopic object can be considerable.

you said 'The issue is that the concept of equilibrium applies to big systems (+ the environment).' then how come closed/isolated system no environment attains eqbm.

@MantuDas That closed/isolated systems even exist is also an approximation. A simple example of something that can not be shielded at all is electric charge. Neither can gravitation be shielded, so even if we had a perfectly closed box, all internal particle motion would equilibrate with the temperature of the environment of the box through gravitation. If you decide to ignore this, then you will get into the realms of the Poincare recurrence theorem, which basically states that all isolated systems will be returning infinitesimally close to their initial state.

I have been inprecise. I meant: the concept of thermodynamic equilibrium applies (strictly speaking) to big systems with multiple components. It is a bit of a stretch to talk about the equilibrium of a single isolated pendulum. With "enviornment" I was referring to what is "around" of the component you focus on, i.e. in the case of a pendulum it would be the air although strictly speaking you always have the whole universe interacting with your system (of course, negligibly usually). In other words. Even an isolated pendulum needs to have something around it to do "thermodynamics".

I think there are several possible answers for this problem. It is definitely true that the system will converge to its equilibrium state if you properly consider dissipation, as JalfredP answered. But I think the question actually touches the very foundation of statistical physics.
In a more theoretical answer, I would say that statistical physics and its most basic canonical ensemble is only justified when the system you are considering is chaotic. For example, it's not only a single pendulum, but also other systems such as...

A system with a bunch of pendulums that don't interact with each other.
A three-body planetary system with one of the stable periodic solutions.
A wave system that follows the KdV equation for time evolution.

...that doesn't converge to the canonical ensemble.
What these systems have in common are that they're all "exactly solvable" and because of the presence of large number of conserved quantities, the time evolution is forever predictable. In such cases, it is not really justified to treat the system with those equilibrium distributions unless the system is coupled to a bath (dissipation). In such cases with a bath/environment, there are chaotic degrees of freedom there, which again allows one to use stat-mech.
The whole point of stat-mech is that because we can't calculate the exact time evolution of the system, that very fact actually allows us to use a statistical description of the system. This is why it is basically necessary to have many degrees of freedom, because if we only have a few degrees of freedom it will most likely be easy to just calculate all the time evolution degrees of freedom exactly.
